# Having trouble working through more complex array slicing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-slicing

I'm working through [the 100 numpy exercise list](https://github.com/rougier/numpy-100). One of the questions asks for you to devise an array of all ones, and then add a border of 0's.

There are two ways given to solve this. The first makes a lot sense (just using the `.pad` method, etc.) The second relies on more complex slicing. The code given for this is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

Z = np.ones((5, 5)) 
Z[:, [0, -1]] = 0
Z[[0, -1], :] = 0
print(Z)
```

Can anyone clear up for me what is going on in this code? I tried playing around with it, but some of the ways it changes don't make a lot of intuitive sense. For instance, if I just delete line 2, seemingly nothing changes? But if I change the second value in line 3 from -1 to 3, a lot changes.

As a minor addendum, could anyone explain to me why methods like `np.ones` etc. require two sets of parentheses?

Comment: `ones` requires one positional argument, which may be a scalar or tuple.  Any extra arguments are understood to be the keyword ones, `dtype` and `order`.  This is common python practice.

Answer (score 0):

- Line 1: make an array of 1's with shape `(5, 5)` (hence the two sets of parentheses: one to call the function, one to provide the shape tuple).
- Line 2: set the first and last (index -1) **column** to 0. Unpacking the slice: the `:` means 'everything in the first dimension' (i.e. all rows) and the `[0, -1]` means 'the first and last' (you're allowed to index with a list or array in NumPy, not just with integers).
- Line 3: set the first and last **row** to 0.
- Line 4: print it.

If you delete line 2, something changes, look again.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!